# Puppeteer-generated PDF is displaying weird characters after writing it to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, puppeteer

[image]

I'm reading HTML files directly from an AWS S3 bucket using Node.js and opening them with Puppeteer to convert them into PDFs. However, the PDFs generated from this process are displaying strange characters instead of the expected content.

I've explored several troubleshooting steps in an attempt to resolve this issue:

Content Types: I have experimented with different content types for the HTML files in the S3 bucket to ensure they are interpreted correctly.

Puppeteer Arguments: I've adjusted various Puppeteer arguments, such as page settings and viewport, to see if they have any impact on the PDF output.

Despite these efforts, I have not made any significant progress in resolving the issue. Any assistance or guidance in debugging and fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium-min");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

  // Define the output S3 bucket and key for the PDF file
  const outputBucket = "hygistics.reports";
  const outputKey = key.replace(".html", ".pdf");

  let browser;
  try {
    // Launch Chromium using chrome-aws-lambda
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(
        "https://github.com/Sparticuz/chromium/releases/download/v116.0.0/chromium-v116.0.0-pack.tar"
      ),
      headless: chromium.headless,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      args: [...chromium.args, "--hide-scrollbars", "--disable-web-security"],
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Load the HTML content from S3
    const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: key };
    const htmlContent = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    // Set up the page and content
    await page.setContent(htmlContent.Body.toString(), {
      waitUntil: "networkidle2",
    });

    // Convert HTML to PDF
    const pdf = await page.pdf({
      format: "A4",
      printBackground: true,
      margin: { top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm", left: "1cm" },
    });

    // Upload the PDF to the output S3 bucket
    const uploadParams = {
      Bucket: outputBucket,
      Key: outputKey,
      Body: pdf,
      ContentType: "application/pdf",
    };
    await s3.putObject(uploadParams).promise();

    console.log(
      `HTML to PDF conversion successful. PDF file saved to: s3://${outputBucket}/${outputKey}`
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error converting HTML to PDF:", error);
  } finally {
    if (browser !== null) {
      await browser.close();
    }
  }

  context.succeed("HTML to PDF conversion completed");
};
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the issue is.  As you can see from the screen shot that is a PDF file (look at the first few characters).  How are you loading the PDF?  Download one locally to check it but it looks like the conversion is successful but the display isn't.  It looks like you're setting the content-type but something isn't working with it

Comment: I printed the toString("utf-8") and it still the same. Not sure why.